# Finding files by time of day

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, timestamp, file-search, advanced-query-syntax

Is it possible to search for files (in Windows) by a specific time of day (or range of times) **irrespective of the date**?

For example, I have a folder full of screenshots and I need to select the ones that were taken at a specific time, for example between 6pm to 11pm), regardless of what day they were taken).

Sorting in Explorer is no good because it sorts by the full timestamp, thus mixing the ones taken at night with the ones taken during the day.

Using [AQS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266512%28VS.85%29.aspx) with queries like `*: 18-23` returns files modified on the 18th to the 23rd of any month. (Here, `*:` means `date:`, `datemodified:`, `modified:`, etc. heretofore shortened to just `:`.) Searching for `18:00 .. 23:00` does not work and returns no results. Using the *contains* operators (`~=`) does not seem to help either since `~= 6:`, `~= 18:`, and `~= pm` return nothing, and `~= 18` returns incorrect results.

Is it possible in *any* way?

<sub>(I find it difficult to fathom that this use-case scenario has been overlooked and/or ignored since it is not unusual.)</sub>

Comment: Sounds like a job for PowerShell if you can live with a list or having the files copied to a separate folder, all but those deleted, etc. You could probably pull something off with an elaborate batch script or using some dynamic VB script logic too. You say you need to ""Select" the ones that were taken at a specific time" so you are selecting these from an File Explorer view to open, save to a separate folder or delete all those not in this time frame otherwise, etc.? How Windows do you need the solution to be?

Comment: Well for my current scenario, the need is to move them to a different folder, so using PowerShell would be less than convenient. This isn’t the first time this issue has come up either, and usually it is something similar (moving files around as opposed to just getting a list).